# Does compacted chagelog topic contains one key for each window in Kafka Streams?

Tags: apache-kafka, streaming, apache-kafka-streams

As far as I understood, change log topic for window aggregation should contain at least one key/value for each window?

```
input
  .groupByKey() // group by user
  .windowedBy(
    TimeWindows
      .of(Duration.ofSeconds(60))
      .advanceBy(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
      .grace(Duration.ofSeconds(60)))
  .aggregate(
    () -> new Aggregate(config),
    (userId, msg, aggregate) -> aggregate.addAndReturn(msg),
    Materialized
      .<String, Aggregate>as(inMemoryWindowStore(
        config.getOutputStore(),
        Duration.ofSeconds(300),
        Duration.ofSeconds(60),
        false))
      .withCachingDisabled()
      .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
      .withValueSerde(new MyCustomSerde()));
```

When I query state store, I would expect to get one Key/Value for each window:

```
WindowStoreIterator<Aggregate> iter = store.fetch(userId, start, end)
```

But either I don't get anything (the iterator is empty) or sometimes it is less than the actual number of windows between start-end.

Comment: Have you tried to use `Materialized#withLoggingEnabled()`?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous No, but isn't it enabled by default? I can see there are some messages on change log topic via monitoring interfaces.

Comment: Yes it should be enabled but I would try it, too.

Answer (score 0):

You use the parameters of `store.fetch(key, startTs, endTs)` incorrectly. The two timestamps `startTs` and `endTs` do **not** refer to a single window's start/end timestamp, but it's a *time range*: `fetch()` will return all windows with a start-timestamps that is included in the time range.

The JavaDocs in older versions are not very good to be fair and may be miss leading. Newer versions have improved JavaDocs: https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/state/ReadOnlyWindowStore.html

Note that the parameter types are changes and renamed in newer versions:

> ```
> WindowStoreIterator<V> fetch(K key,
>                              Instant from,
>                              Instant to)
>
> Get all the key-value pairs with the given key and the time range from all the existing windows.
> This iterator must be closed after use.
>
> The time range is inclusive and applies to the starting timestamp of the window.
> ```